# Quadratic equations with word problems

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, word-problem

Find the two-digit number such that its ones digit is one bigger than its tens digit, and the product of the desired number and the sum of digits is $616$.
Answer is $56$.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: To find the number (56) but show the way of solution. 5+6*(56)=616

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say the tens digit is $A$, so the ones digit is $A+1$.

Then the number is $10A+(A+1)$, and the sum of digits is $A+(A+1)$.

You want $(10A+(A+1))(A+(A+1))=616$.

That's $(11A+1)(2A+1)=616$.

Equivalently, $22A^2+13A-615=0$.

Can you solve for $A$?

(There are two solutions, but only one is relevant.)